# Single-threaded vs Multi-threaded CPU Loads in SBCL

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, common-lisp, cpu-usage, sbcl

I'm curious about a Common Lisp program I've written that can run either in single or multi threaded mode (for various inputs) on SBCL (using the Lparallel library). The program seems to run fine and gives the same correct results for inputs in both modes. True to design, it also gives results significantly faster in parallel mode.

However, I notice that both modes load the CPU the same at around 15%. Why doesn't running on all cores load the CPU more?

Other info:

```
SBCL 2.3.0 under Windows 11
Intel i7-9700K clocked at 5.0 on all 8 cores
Normal, minimal background processing
```

Comment: This seems more a question about the load reporting tools in Windows than Lisp.

Comment: if the CPU is not doing anything, is it waiting?

Comment: When the program is not running, the background CPU utilization is consistently 2-4%

Comment: @ignis volens Yes, it would seem so, since all cores are fully occupied by design of the program.